# TypeError: Member "current" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CountersUpgradeable.Counter storage ref

Tags: solidity, upgrading, contract-upgrading

Anyone know a solution for this error: `TypeError: Member "current" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CountersUpgradeable.Counter storage ref.`?

- Creating a V3 contract with a `public view` method `totalSupply()`.
- I want to read the value of `_tokenIds` from the inherited V1 contract (`CountersUpgradeable.Counter internal _tokenIds`)

V3 contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "V2.sol";

contract V3 is V2 {

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }
}
```

V2 Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/CountersUpgradeable.sol";

contract V2 {
    using CountersUpgradeable for CountersUpgradeable.Counter;
    CountersUpgradeable.Counter internal _tokenIds;
}
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Member "current" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CountersUpgradeable.Counter storage ref.
```

Does anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `using XX for YY` isn't inherited.

If you want to keep the nice interface for `_tokenIds` you have to do something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "V2.sol";

contract V3 is V2 {
    //// ---------- Add this line ------------
    using CountersUpgradeable for CountersUpgradeable.Counter;
    //// ----------- until here --------------

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be marked as answer!